# How would I refactor reactive values in Vue composition API?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Say I have a method block like...

```
const computedStyle = computed(() =>
  normalizeStyle([undefined, styleProp, undefined])
);
const computedClass = computed(() =>
  normalizeClass([
    "button",
    classProp,
    {
      "button--pressed": pressed.value,
      "button--enterheld": enterHeld.value,
      "button--long-pressed": longPressed.value,
    },
  ])
);
```

I'd like to refactor it to something like

```
export const useNormalizedStyles = ({
  style: styleProp,
  class: classProp,
  preClass,
  postClass,
  preStyle,
  postStyle,
}: NormalizedStylesProps): NormalizedStylesResult => {
  const computedStyle = computed(() =>
    normalizeStyle([preStyle, styleProp, postStyle])
  );
  const computedClass = computed(() =>
    normalizeClass([preClass, classProp, postClass])
  );
  return {
    style: computedStyle,
    class: computedClass,
  };
};
```

with the call

```
const { style: computedStyle, class: computedClass } = useNormalizedStyles({
  style: styleProp,
  preClass: "button",
  class: classProp,
  postClass: {
    "button--pressed": pressed.value,
    "button--enterheld": enterHeld.value,
    "button--long-pressed": longPressed.value,
  },
});
```

But when I do it, it does not appear to update. I am thinking I just need a `reactive` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it working with this

```
const { style: computedStyle, class: computedClass } = useNormalizedStyles({
  style: styleProp,
  preClass: "button",
  class: classProp,
  postClass: reactive({
    "button--pressed": pressed,
    "button--enterheld": enterHeld,
    "button--long-pressed": longPressed,
  }),
});
```

Some thing to note... the `reactive` values should only contain the refs and not `.value`